# Use jQuery's .load() to load page fragments but replaces everything in body

Tags: javascript, jquery, page-fragments

I want to replace the original div.wrapcontent with the contents of a fragment. But using .load replaces everything in the body, not just the specific div.

```
        $("nav#category-nav>ul>li").on("click", "a", function() {
        var $thecontent = $("#thecontent"),
        $wrapcontent = $("#thecontent > .wrapcontent");

        var path = $(this).attr("href");

        $wrapcontent.load(path);
    });
```

Comment: No need for `$thecontent` at all. On a different note, are you sure the body is being replaced or is the page navigating to the `href`. I believe you need to prevent the default anchor behavior (which is navigation) by using something like `evt.preventDefault();`. Otherwise your link is going to redirect your page. Check the URL after clicking the link...

Comment: Not with the code as presented, only the content inside `#thecontent > .wrapcontent` will be replaced by that `load` call. Best to create a [minimal replicating example](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @War10ck: Ah, yes, that's it. There's no `preventDefault` / `return false`. The `load` call isn't completing at all. (That's an *answer*, btw.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem stems from the default behavior of an anchor tag. By default, anchor tags redirect to their `href`. For your use case, you have to capture this default behavior and prevent it from occuring.

Add the `evt` object to the function and prevent the default behavior like so:

```
$("nav#category-nav>ul>li").on("click", "a", function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var $thecontent = $("#thecontent"),
        $wrapcontent = $("#thecontent > .wrapcontent");

    var path = $(this).attr("href");

    $wrapcontent.load(path);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended this line with semicolon not comma
and use `e.preventDefault();`

```
var $thecontent = $("#thecontent");
```

Comment: In this particular case, it happens not to matter. That's not the OP's problem.

Comment: The OP is actually declaring a variable across multiple lines. The same line could be written like so `var $thecontent = $('#thecontent"), $wrapcontent = $('#thecontent > .wrapcontent');` all as one line. Both methods are syntactically correct.

Comment: ohhhh yes i forgot u dont have use var again